# Conversion from netcdf to raster (tif) changes resolution and extent?

Tags: python, r, netcdf, python-xarray, terra

I'm trying to convert a netcdf file into raster (tif) format. I have created a script and it worked fine a while ago. But now, when I try to use the same simple script with a different file, the resolution changes from `0.5 x 0.5` to `0.5 x 0.5263158`. Also the extent moves from:

```
-100.25, -73.25, 28.75, 48.75
```

to

```
-100.5, -73, 28.48684, 49.01316
```

I have also tried with different raster packages in R, yet they come back with a message saying that cells are not equally spaced. It could be very well an issue with the file (attached [here](https://github.com/dumontgoulart/hybrid_model_paper_two/blob/main/hybrid_gfdl-esm4_ssp126_default_yield_soybean_shift_2017-2044.nc)), but I could not see where and how.

Code for reproduction:

```
# load netcdf file
import xarray as xr 
import rioxarray

xds = xr.open_dataset('output_shocks_us/hybrid_gfdl-esm4_ssp126_2015co2_yield_soybean_shift_2017-2044.nc')
xds = xds.rename({'lat':'y','lon':'x', 'time':'band'})

# Add CRS
xds.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)

# Convert to geotiff
xds["yield-soy-noirr"].rio.to_raster('hybrid_gfdl-esm4_ssp126_2015co2_yield_soybean_shift_2017-2044_test.tif')
rio = xr.open_rasterio("hybrid_gfdl-esm4_ssp126_2015co2_yield_soybean_shift_2017-2044_test.tif")

print(xds)
print(rio)
```

The full results are:

```
print(xds)
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:          (y: 39, x: 55)
Coordinates:
    band             int64 2025
  * y                (y) float64 28.75 30.25 30.75 31.25 ... 47.75 48.25 48.75
  * x                (x) float64 -100.2 -99.75 -99.25 ... -74.25 -73.75 -73.25
    spatial_ref      int32 0
Data variables:
    yield-soy-noirr  (y, x) float64 nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan nan
Attributes:
    grid_mapping:  spatial_ref

############
print(rio)
<xarray.DataArray (band: 1, y: 39, x: 55)>
array([[[     nan,      nan, ...,      nan,      nan],
        [     nan,      nan, ...,      nan,      nan],
        ...,
        [     nan, 0.672842, ...,      nan,      nan],
        [     nan,      nan, ...,      nan,      nan]]])
Coordinates:
  * band     (band) int32 1
  * y        (y) float64 28.75 29.28 29.8 30.33 30.86 ... 47.17 47.7 48.22 48.75
  * x        (x) float64 -100.2 -99.75 -99.25 -98.75 ... -74.25 -73.75 -73.25
Attributes:
    transform:      (0.5, 0.0, -100.5, 0.0, 0.5263157894736842, 28.4868421052...
    crs:            +init=epsg:4326
    res:            (0.5, -0.5263157894736842)
    is_tiled:       0
    nodatavals:     (nan,)
    scales:         (1.0,)
    offsets:        (0.0,)
    descriptions:   ('yield-soy-noirr',)
    AREA_OR_POINT:  Area
    grid_mapping:   spatial_ref
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably not waiting for anyone to answer here anymore, but I'd like to provide an attempt of an answer hereby:

When reading the netCDF file using `terra`, several problems are evident. There is no coordinate reference system provided, no extent defined and your resolution differs in direction of x and y. Like you said in your question, just wanted to confirm.

```r
nc <- terra::rast("hybrid_gfdl-esm4_ssp126_default_yield_soybean_shift_2017-2044.nc")
nc
#> Error in R_nc4_open: Invalid argument
#> Warning: [rast] GDAL did not find an extent. Cells not equally spaced?
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 39, 55, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.01818182, 0.02564103  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. :  
#> source      : hybrid_gfdl-esm4_ssp126_default_yield_soybean_shift_2017-2044.nc:yield-soy-noirr 
#> varname     : yield-soy-noirr 
#> name        : yield-soy-noirr
```

`terra` throws a warning, not an error, and nevertheless creates a SpatRaster object.

Since we know the dimensions of your raster (x: 55, y: 39) and the resolution (0.5°), I suspect - please prove me wrong! - that this is inconsistent with the extent provided assuming the lower left corner of your bounding box is correct:

```r
# x
seq(from = -100.25, by = 0.5, length.out = 55 + 1) |> range()
#> [1] -100.25  -72.75

# y
seq(from = 28.75, by = 0.5, length.out = 39 + 1) |> range()
#> [1] 28.75 48.25
```

... and the result after manually adjusting attributes looks quite promising since your resolution now has the expected values:

```
terra::ext(nc) <- c(-100.25, -72.75, 28.75, 48.25)
terra::crs(nc) <- "epsg:4326"

nc
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 39, 55, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
#> extent      : -100.25, -72.75, 28.75, 48.25  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> source      : hybrid_gfdl-esm4_ssp126_default_yield_soybean_shift_2017-2044.nc:yield-soy-noirr 
#> varname     : yield-soy-noirr 
#> name        : yield-soy-noirr
```

The resulting SpatRaster object can be written to disk using:

```r
terra::writeRaster(nc, "hybrid_gfdl-esm4_ssp126_default_yield_soybean_shift_2017-2044.tif")
```

Comment: What lead you to `n+1` in your reasoning? Though I suppose 'needing a bigger number' might answer in this SpatRaster noir mystery.

Comment: At this point it was just part of trial and error without overthinking, but if you take a moment, you'll realize that you e.g. need `n` iterations to cover all grid centers (c.f. dimensions) in x or y but `n+1` iterations to get the extent, since usually one is starting from the lower left corner. On the `n-th` iteration you will have reached the inner border of your last cell and will need one more step to reach the outer border needed for full coverage.

Comment: That's clear, thanks, and I liked the `seq/range` in pursuit of extent as expressed here. I follow your stuff when I see it.

Comment: Always happy to help! ;-)