# How do i put my cropped imgage back together?

Tags: r, image, merge

I have the following problem: I had to split my image into 2 parts because editing was not possible due to the size of the file. Now I have to put my area back together so that it is again the area from the beginning and I can therefore show a complete analysis of the area. I have already used "merge" which then calculated for 2 hours and then came out with a faulty file. Is there a better function for images? Im working wirh R. And i guess my merge function does only work on RasterObjects. So i just need an alternativ for Images I hope you understand my problem.

Here is what i did:
So at first i cropped my Raster into 2 parts by help of a defined  polygon

In short: y <- crop (x,definedPolygon)
Next  i transformed this smaler Raster into an Image: I <- as.im.RasterLayer (function by maptools)
Next i did a spatial smoothing.
SI<-Smooth.im(I, sigma=1,bleed=TRUE,kernal=gaussian)
All steps were also performed for the 2 area.
Now I would like to convert the two images that were spatially smoothed back to their origin so that it shows the entire area from the beginning.
Summarized that I have spatially smoothed my entire area and not my 2 sub-areas

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Perhaps SI_sgdf  <- as.SpatialGridDataFrame.im(SI), SI_raster <- as(SI_sgdf, 'RasterLayer'), SI_rast <- terra::rast(SI_raster), same with SI2, then terra::merge(SI_rast, SI2_rast). If your definedPolygon undershot, see [repairing extent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70687589/conversion-from-netcdf-to-raster-tif-changes-resolution-and-extent/73214250#comment129310506_73214250). By undershot, definedPolygon left gap between 1 & 2 rather than overlap.

Comment: It  works really well! Thank u. There was no error or something. All values are fitting perfekt. Even the parts that overlap fit in very well. And overshot  or something are no problem.

Comment: I'm glad to hear. Write up your approach/code to solve as an answer and then accept it, as this will help others in the future. And keep in mind the link, as it still might help in future as well.